# How do I recover a keyring password on ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, server, password

I already tried

> rm /home/$USER/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring

But it says the file doesn't exist.

Is there anyway I can recover or change the keyring password on ubuntu server 18.04?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. `rm` will delete a file, not recover it. As for file recovery on Ubuntu Server, if the system is using ZFS or an LVM with snapshots, then you can restore the file from a recent snapshot. Otherwise, you'll need to grab a recent backup.

Comment: I don't think I made any backups...